# Почему функция по событию resize не срабатывает?

Tags: javascript

```js
var documentBody = document.querySelector('body');
if(documentBody.addEventListener) {
 documentBody.addEventListener('resize', adaptiveImg);
} else {
 documentBody.attachEvent('onersize', adaptiveImg);
}

function adaptiveImg() {
 console.log(20);
}
```

Пробовал различными способами, и вешать событие на объект window, пробовал подключать без помощи слушателя событий, результат один и тот же. При изменении окна браузера ничего не происходит. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Опечатки, как в `'onersize'`?

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', adaptiveImg);
function adaptiveImg() {
  console.log(20);
}
```

Comment: Очень странно, делал точно так же, не знаю почему не вышло, может где-то ошибку синтаксическую сделал.